# Add top/bottom views to UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my storyboard I have UITableViewController which has custom class.
How can I add UIView objects on top and bottom parts of the table view?

Do I have to create UITableView and two desired views inside of UIView and then manually init my controller, set tableView or there is a better way?

Comment: do you want to add the views into the header/footer of the first/last section? then you could use the `UITableViewDelegate`'s methods `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`

Comment: Depends if you want the views to scroll with the view or not

Comment: I want the views to be static, not scroll and not obscure table items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're wanting to use UITableViewController for it's abilities to manage cells and static layouts, the best possibility would be to use a container view in your storyboard.  This would allow you to layout the main view contents around the table and still keep a separate UITableViewController maintaining the table itself.  Set up the right auto layout constraints (really simple, just anchor the container view to the header and footer views)

[image]

Comment: Yeah, container view is really very useful in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible in UITableViewConroller:

```
    let bottomView = UIView()
    bottomView.backgroundColor = .red // or your color
    bottomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 78, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 78) // 78 or your size of view
    navigationController?.view.addSubview(bottomView)
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

[image]

Comment: however if you do this, will the table view not scroll behind the new view?  How do you get it to respect the space of the new view?

Answer (score -2):

Something like this should work for you:

```
// Your frame/view will vary
UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 44)];
subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.navigationController.view addSubview:subview];
```

Comment: You said you wanted it to be static and not scroll with the table view

Comment: exactly, neither it should obscure table. I mentioned it in comment.

Comment: Simply change the frame of your table view then to start at the bottom of the subview