# How to manually bind UITableViewController class to UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In storyboard you can creating `UITableViewController`, assign your custom class to it and your custom class will fully represent `UITableView`. However, when I don't have UITableViewController, but have UITableView only somewhere in the storyboard, how can I fully bind it to my table controller class?

I have outlet to my UITableView in the class where I intend to create table view controller. Then I am creating controller and assigning tableView to outlet:

```
_catalogTVC = [[CatalogueTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
_catalogTVC.tableView = _tableViewOutlet;
```

This unfortunately doesn't full bind table controller because no data source or delegate messages are dispatched to my table view controller class. I wonder what other stuff storyboard does in order to bind them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is looks as bad idea, but if you really need this set `delegate` and `dataSource` of  `_tableViewOutlet`, something like this:

```
_tableViewOutlet.dataSource = _catalogTVC;
_tableViewOutlet.delegate = _catalogTVC;
```

Comment: Yeah I know it's bad, but it comes from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483845/add-top-bottom-views-to-uitableviewcontroller) problem. However, even after your suggestion my table view controller is not calling delegate methods.

Comment: @Pablo can you set breakpoint to this lines and check that `_tableViewOutlet` and `_catalogTVC` not null?

Comment: and one another guess, you should have strong pointer to `_catalogTVC` because delegate property is weak, and it can be released

Comment: yep, weak was the issue. Looks like it started to work. If you see better solution for the mentioned problem in my other question, please suggest. thanks. +1/upvote.

Comment: thanks, and sorry, I looked your another question but cant help you with it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... thinking about your original issue, if you're wanting to use UITableViewController for it's abilities to manage cells and static layouts, the best possibility would be to use a container view in your storyboard.  This would allow you to layout the main view contents around the table and still keep a separate UITableViewController maintaining the table itself.  Set up the right auto layout constraints (really simple, just anchor the container view to the header and footer views)

[image]

Comment: That's worth to try indeed. Let me get back to you soon. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that works much nicer. You can move your answer to original question so I can accept there.

Comment: My pleasure, I have a feeling I'm going to have to convert some of my own view controllers to use this sometime real soon since Xcode 5.1 now requires a UITableViewController to use a static layout.