# how to add item to scroll with tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have a uitableview which basically is just a settings menu and each cell just pushes another view controller. However, I have a logout button at the bottom and want it to stick to the botom of the tableview and also scroll with it when a user scrolls the table view up or down. If you need any more clarification, please ask. Thanks!

Comment: By "stick to the botom of the TableView", do you mean like another cell?

Comment: can you show by image what do you mean exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486360/1536753

Please check this answer. :)